# Ternary operator shorthand that returns same value if condition is true with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

is there a shorthand for this with Lodash? (or maybe Vanilla JS/TypeScript)

`var val = obj.value !== undefined : obj.value : '';`

Have in mind that `var val = obj.value || '';` is not valid as `0 | false` are valid values but falsy values.

Thanks.

Comment: Returns the same value, `undefined`, `true`, or what?

Comment: shouldn't it be: `obj.value !== undefined ? obj.value : '';`

Comment: yeah but I wanna avoid puting obj.value twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lodash you can use [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get). The method 3rd optional parameter is a default that will be returned if the property is `undefined`:

```js
var obj = { anotherValue: 'not default' };

var val = _.get(obj, 'value', 'default');
var anotherVal = _.get(obj, 'anotherValue', 'default');

console.log('value:', val);
console.log('anotherVal:', anotherVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is support for `ES6`, you can use destructuring and default parameters, which is abstracted by the JS engine.

```
function validate( {
   value = ''
} = {}) {
   // The default parameters are part of the function 
   // signature, which helps in keeping the function body 
   // clean without any boilerplate code for default values

  console.log('value: ' + value );
}

validate({ value: 100 });  // value: 100
validate({ value: 0 });    // value: 0
validate();                // value:
```

There are 2 patterns which are being used here

```
{
  value = ''
} = {}
```

The one which follows the equals is the default value, which is expected for the object and the nesting inside the flower braces which is the destructuring pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring allows you to set default value (ES6 feature). For example:

```
const {val = ''} = obj
```

Comment: destructing needs to use the same names as in the object. const {val} = obj will cause val = undefined. If value is the name of the attribute in the object then you can rename it during destructing with a colon. So for example if you wanted to rename value to val and give it a default value of '' do this: const {value: val=''} = obj

Answer (score 0):

ES6 destructuring (`val = ''` only if value is undefined):

```
var {value: val=''} = obj;
```